# Select dependable dropdown list in web form

Tags: vba

```
   <pre>     
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSection" 
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSection\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlSection" class="Dropdown">

    <option value="0">----Select-----</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="131518424">A</option>
    <option value="131518425">B</option>
    <option value="131518426">C</option>
    <option value="131518427">D</option>
    <option value="131518428">E</option>
    <option value="131518429">F</option>
    <option value="131518430">G</option>
    <option value="131518431">H</option>
    <option value="131518432">I</option>
    <option value="131518433">J</option>

</select>
</pre>
```

Comment: Your code do not run here , wrong password

Comment: Can you add screenshots of the web form?

Comment: Can you add the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit] ? And I see no attempt to assign "A" to an element. Which line is your second dropdown assignment for "A" ?

Comment: Please read  doc.getElementById("txtUserName").Value = "09100107801-01"

Comment: why is this tagged VBA ?

Comment: It is tagged VBA becase it involves VBA automation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code do not run here , invalid password , but you could try something like that

```
   Dim opts As Object
    Dim opt As Object

    Set opts = IE.document.getElementsById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddldiability")

    For Each opt In opts
        If opt.innerText = "A" Then
            opt.Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    opts.FireEvent ("onchange")
```

Comment: Please read  login id as "09100107801-01" and password as "Abc@1234".

Comment: Thax for trying to help. But it dose'nt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write slightly using `With syntax`.

Add wait conditions ideally for spinner to disappear, or if page uses ajax you can try monitoring for that to complete, rather than explicit waits (which I have used); traditional page load waits won't suffice. The waits before attempting to select from dropdowns might be sufficient but you could also attach the event you want to fire and then fire that.

Enclose your username in "" so is passed as string literal.

The bottom calls should be using `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`

You can use an attribute selector via querySelector to make dropdown selections.

Let's say your dropdown options were as follows:

```html
<select name="alphabetSoup" form="aForm">
<option value ="1">A</option>
<option value ="2">B</option>
<option value ="3">C</option>
</select>
```

You can use an attribute selector to target the option that is `"A"` by using its `value` attribute and `value` attribute value:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[value='1']")
```

where 1 is the value of the `value` attribute of the `option` tag element for `"A"`

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillForm()
    Dim ie As Object, tool As Workbook

    Set tool = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://student.udise.in/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .getElementById("txtUserName").Value = "username"
            .getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "password"
            .getElementById("btnSubmit").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .Navigate2 "https://student.udise.in/Userscreens/Profilenew4.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim evt As Object
        Set evt = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        evt.initEvent "change", True, False

        With .document.querySelector("[value='536']")
            .Selected = True
            .dispatchEvent evt
        End With

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

        With .document.querySelector("[value='131518424']") '< insert option A value attribute value here. Same as shown for 536 above.
            .Selected = True
            .dispatchEvent evt
        End With

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)

        With .document
            .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddldiability").Focus
            .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddldiability").selectedIndex = 2
            .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddldiability").FireEvent "onchange"
        End With

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

        Stop

        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u very much for trying to help me. I have tried as you said but still no effect.

Comment: Really? What value did you insert for valueForOptionAGoesHere ? Pretty sure it should work. You can also add another second to the wait e.g. Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)

Comment: I have tried to to put the value "131518424" as attribute in the query selector and also tried to change the time value no effect. On the fourth  " with " statement the code halts and do not run,

Comment: Is this the fourth  With .document.querySelector("[value='131518424']")  ?

Comment: Yes it is here where the debugger stops.

Comment: With .document.querySelector("[value='131518424']") '< insert option A value attribute value here. Same as shown for 536 above.
            ".Selected = True" it stops at the last line i.e " selected=true"

Comment: Is anything highlighted in yellow in the vbe?

Comment: ".selected = true" this is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: and no error message? You haven't turned off error messages in any way?

Comment: No I have not turned off

Comment: Not sure why code would stop before the STOP line unless an error.

Comment: Thanx QHarr for your help. I had some problem in the codes and I have rectified it. Now your code runs fine. Thanx again.